# Given a grid populated randomly with a subset of numbers, what is the chance that at least one whole row or column contains exactly one unique number?

Tags: probability

A grid has $c$ columns and $r$ rows. Each cell in the grid is populated with one of $n$ possible numbers. What is the probability that at least one row and/or column contains the same number in all of its cells?

I have attempted to solve this like so, assuming (wrongly, I now believe) that the column matching condition and the row matching condition are independent events:

1. Chance that a given column in isolation meets the matching condition:

   $P_C=(1/n)^r \times n$
2. Chance that a given row in isolation meets the matching condition:

   $P_R=(1/n)^c \times n$
3. Chance that at least one column in the grid meets the matching condition:

   $P_{C+}=1-(1-P_C)^c$
4. Chance that at least one row in the grid meets the matching condition:

   $P_{R+}=1-(1-P_R)^r$
5. Chance of any row or column matching (prospective solution):

   $1-(1-P_{C+})(1-P_{R+})$

I have programmatically determined the correct solution under multiple conditions:

- $c = 2, r = 2, n = 2$: formula says $15/16$ (should be $14/16$)
- $c = 2, r = 3, n = 2$: formula says $119/128$ (should be $29/32$)
- $c = 3, r = 3, n = 2$: formula says $3367/4096$ (should be $205/256$)
- $c = 4, r = 4, n = 2$: formula says $11012415/16777216$ (should be $21331/32768$)

Fascinatingly, the larger the grid is, the smaller the margin of error is.

Where did I go wrong? What should I study to better understand problems like this one?

Comment: "Fascinatingly, the larger the grid is, the smaller the margin of error is." Actually, that's to be expected, because as the events get more improbable, they also tend to be more independent

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,\dots,c$ let $E_{i}$ denote the event that all numbers
are the same in column $i$.

For $j=1,\dots,r$ let $F_{i}$ denote the event that all numbers
are the same in row $j$.

Then to be found is $P\left(E_{1}\cup\cdots\cup E_{c}\cup F_{1}\cup\cdots\cup F_{r}\right)$.

This can be done with inclusion/exclusion and under the convention
that $P\left(\cap\varnothing\right)=1$ we find:

$$P\left(E_{1}\cup\cdots\cup E_{c}\cup F_{1}\cup\cdots\cup F_{r}\right)=$$$$1-\sum_{i=0}^{c}\sum_{j=0}^{r}\binom{c}{i}\binom{r}{j}\left(-1\right)^{i+j}P\left(E_{1}\cap\cdots\cap E_{i}\cap F_{1}\cap\cdots\cap F_{j}\right)$$

(observe that the term for $i=0=j$ under the summation is $\left(-1\right)^{0}P\left(\cap\varnothing\right)=1$
and that this is compensated by the preceding $1$)

Here: $$P\left(E_{1}\cap\cdots\cap E_{i}\cap F_{1}\cap\cdots\cap F_{j}\right)=n\times n^{ij-ic-jr}$$
so we arrive at probability:

$$1-n\sum_{i=0}^{c}\sum_{j=0}^{r}\binom{c}{i}\binom{r}{j}\left(-1\right)^{i+j}n^{ij-ic-jr}$$

I leave it here now, but later I will have a second look for a sanity check and an effort to simplify the result.